# Validation running app deployed with azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, deployment, devops

I'm probably just missing a term but here's what I would like to do.

I want an azure agent (probably?) to scan a folder or watch active process and make sure the signature of the running (deployed) application is matching the signature of the last artefact deployed in azure pipeline.

I know there is a lot of tools to make sure you deploy the right app with the right permission etc etc. But that's not what I need for now. I want to detect if someone manually deployed the app or if someone (or a virus) tempered with it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

An [Azure Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/) can be configured to [run on a schedule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function); if your application exposes an API which reports its version, you could write a function to check that version and raise a warning if it is wrong.

However; I don't think this would be a good use of time and resources. The better way to mitigate against application redeployment or corruption is to [restrict access to the application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview).